# Border Footer & Header Length Adjustment is SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I am trying to adjust the length of footer and header length in SSRS reports but not able to fix that.I want size of border be same as length of line in data.

**What I Tried :**
1.Try to change the page layout of the page.

2.Not able to find Padding left or padding right in footer or Header.

Screenshot attached of PDF.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Under the report properties (right click on the grey area in SSRS designer) you can change the **Page Setup** which should also effect the border. But I dont like the idea of changing the standard DIN A4 margins or size.

Maybe a better work around is, when you set the **BorderStyle** from the header and footer properties to **None**, and add a simple line just at the end of the border itself. Now you can by yourself chose the length of this line.